# Minimum Quantity for Grouped Product

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, grouped-products, quantity

Is it possible to specify a *minimum quantity* that needs to be purchased for a grouped product?

When I create simple products, I see the option to set the minimum quantity via the "*Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart*" setting under the `Inventory` tab, but when I go to the inventory tab for a grouped product that option is not shown. I can only see three options `Manage Stock`, `Enable Qty Increments` and `Stock Availability`.

I'm using Magento `ver 1.9.0.1` if that makes a difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A group product is just a wrapper of a group of individual products. I said it is a WRAPPER. What should a wrapper hold is purely depends upon the associated products features. Hence MIN QUANTITY and MAX QUANTITY are not relevant for a grouped product, but which are fully controlled by the configuration of it's individual product.

For an example, Suppose we have a *Shoe kit* which is a grouped product. *Shoe-Kit* holds two simple products *Adidas-Large* and *Adidas-Small*. In the default case, you should select any one of the above products quantity to 1 in order to add *Shoe-Kit* to the cart.

Suppose for *Adidas-Large* You have set *min-qty* to 3 and for *Adidas-Small* you have set *max-qty* to 5. After setup this, if you want to add *Shoe-Kit*  to the cart, you should set the quantity of *Adidas-Large* at-least 3 and quantity of *Adidas-Small* should not exceed 5. If any of this rule is violated, you won't be able to add *Shoe-Kit* to the cart.

### In short

Min and Max Quantity of a Grouped Product is completely depends upon it's associated products. If you want to set min and max quantity for a Grouped Product, then you should configure that in it's associated products itself

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense to me, but I don't think it will work for my use case. We have seven possible items to sell together.  In order for a customer to buy this option, they must choose at least three of the individual items and could go as far as purchasing all seven.  From what you described, I can force them to purchase a certain amount of an individual item, but I can't force them to buy 3 of the 7 available.  Any suggestions on how I can achieve that?

Comment: you really need to write an extension for that